# How do I need to escape search string in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I need to search and replace this:

```
ExecIf($["${debug}" = "1"]?NoOp
```

with this:

```
GoSub(chanlog,s,1(1,[${CHANNEL}]
```

I can't seem to do it in vim, and I'm not sure what needs to be escaped, as nothing I've tried works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to escape the `[]` and the spaces:

```
:s/ExecIf($\["${debug}"\ =\ "1"\]?NoOp/GoSub(chanlog,s,1(1,\[${CHANNEL}\]/
```

just a bit trial and error

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change a long string with lots of punctuation characters, and it's an exact match (you don't want any of them to be treated as regex syntax) you can use the `nomagic` option, to have the search pattern interpreted as a literal string.

```
:set nomagic
:%s/ExecIf($["${debug}" = "1"]?NoOp/GoSub(chanlog,s,1(1,[${CHANNEL}]/
:set magic
```

You still have to watch out for the delimiters (the slashes of the `s///` command) but you can use any character for that, it doesn't have to be a slash, so when you have something like this and there are slashes in the search or replace string, just pick something else, like `s@foo@bar@` or `s:bar:baz:`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having problems with which characters to escape in a vim substitution (<kbd>:s//</kbd>), remember the `nomagic` concept, and in particular the `nomagic` version of a substitute: <kbd>:snomagic//</kbd> or <kbd>:sno//</kbd>. `nomagic` means: interpret each character literally.

So this should work without worrying about escaping characters in the substitution:

```
:sno/ExecIf($["${debug}" = "1"]?NoOp/GoSub(chanlog,s,1(1, [${CHANNEL}]/
```

Get to know magic vs. nomagic, <kbd>:sno//</kbd>, and <kbd>\v</kbd>, <kbd>\V</kbd>:

```
:help magic
```

The nomagic version of a *search* for your string uses `\V`:

```
/\VExecIf($["${debug}" = "1"]?NoOp
```

Comment: I tried using the `sno/...`, bt get the same result; it says the pattern was not found.

Comment: hrm first make sure neither of us has a typo. Then turn on `incsearch` with `:set incsearch`, and then start typing the nomagic search: `/\VExecIf` ... and make sure you get matches in your file that way. Also, does the magic substitute (escaping the first `[`) work for you?